# hashset retrieving same element

Tags: java, hashset

I am using HashSet collection since I am interested in unique (no duplicate) elements.
I noticed that I can get all elements of a HashSet using an iterator. 
My (simple) question is whether I can retrieve the same element twice (or more times). To be more specific in the following code

```
HashSet<String> vectors = new HashSet<String>();
Iterator iterator = vectors.iterator(); 
String temp;
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    temp = (String) iterator.next();
    System.out.println("Next element inside HashSet is " + temp);
    out.write(temp + "\n");
}
```

I am using `temp` to store the value of HashSet and to use it twice (one time to display it and one time to write it to a stream. Is there a way to *stay* in the same element? 
I think if I use a syntax like:

```
System.out.println("Next element inside HashSet is " + iterator.next());
out.write(iterator.next() + "\n");
```

I will get only have the elements (the other half will be displayed only). Isn't that the case?

Comment: There's a way to use the same element twice, and that's the way you're already using it. `next` always moves forward one step. Why is using `temp` a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are only reading the elements of the Set, I would recommend a [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop, which is basically the same as your code (the first snippet) but has been designed for this kind of situations (and is more readable IMO).

```
HashSet<String> vectors = new HashSet<String>();
for(String temp : vectors){
    System.out.println("Next element inside HashSet is " + temp);
    out.write(temp + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HashSet.iterator there is no way to retrieve an element without moving on to the next one.

If you want something like this consider using a stack with pop, push and top methods.

although, I see no reason to do what you have done with temp. Its normal, elegant and straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

@Eypros, When you call iterator.next() method, It fetches element and move next that's why you will get half elements.

Answer (score 0):

itt.next() call return current element from itr,move itr pointer by one. and  if you call it again it will return you next element not same.

Answer (score 0):

The `Iterator` from `HashSet` will never return the same `String` twice. However you can use the returned value as many times as needed after assigning it to the variable, how you have already done.

If you call the `next()` on the iterator twice, it returns the two subsequent elements (or throws `NoSuchElementException` if there are not enough elements remaining).

Your mistake is probably you assume `Iterator.hasNext()` changes the state of iterator, advancing to the next position. `hasNext()` does **not** change the iterator state and can be called any number of times. For instance, to print a comma separated list without comma at the end:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(iterator.next());
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
       System.out.print(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Next element inside HashSet is " + iterator.next());
out.write(iterator.next() + "\n");
```

This syntex will give two different elements. If you want same element then either you have to store in "Temp"  like variable or use for-each loop.